# Plot a graph with two series from a range of selected data in Excel using a macro

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I work in a molecular biology laboratory and have obtained a huge datasheet with expression levels of genes in different conditions. I want to automate the process of plotting the different values for each gene. I have no idea of VBA and can only understand roughly the output of the "record macro" function.

My data is arranged as follows (in one row): Gene name, expression in condition1, condition2... up to condition 6. What I want to do is: I want to select a row and after doing the macro, I want to have a plot with conditions 1-3 in one series and 4-6 in a the second series.

When I select the first row and record a macro, I get this:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$A$4:$G$4")
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Delete
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "=Sheet1!$B$3"
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Sheet1!$B$4:$D$4"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Name = "=Sheet1!$E$3"
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Values = "=Sheet1!$E$4:$G$4"
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).XValues = "=Sheet1!$B$2:$D$2"
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)

End Sub
```

This works for the first row, but when I run it on other row of data, I get the first plot as the source of values is fixed. What I would like to change is the fixed values in

```
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Sheet1!$B$4:$D$4"
```

To the second to fourth values in my selected range. And the values in

```
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Values = "=Sheet1!$E$4:$G$4"
```

To the fifth to the seventh values in my selected row.

In addition, if I could add as a title the value in the first cell of the row, it would be really helpful, but that's not my main concern.

Comment: use the information given here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250070/creating-an-excel-macro-for-multiple-graphs-with-the-same-x-values-but-different

Answer (score 0):

You ranges are static because you have dollar signs in front of your R1C1 references. Try removing the dollar signs from you code.

However there is a more dynamic way of doing this using a named range and a pivot table. A dynamic range will automatically shrink and grow as records are added or removed from the range. Define a new range (Formulas/Define Name) and set the "refers to" line to read something like "=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A),7)"

Then create a pivot table with this range as its data source. Then create a pivot chart. Manually create these - but you only have to manually create once.

Then you will need to enter some code on the worksheet double click event (right mouse click the worksheet tab and select 'view code' Enter the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

'Double-click cell to update chart
'You need to create a dynamic range and refer to that range as the pivottable data source
'For this to work you need to create a pivot table and a pivot table chart

If Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'code will only run if values in col A are double clicked

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Dim Pt As PivotTable                                        'refer to pivottables as shorter text 'Pt'
Dim Fd As PivotField                                        'refer to pivottable fields as shorter text 'Fd'
Dim FilterChoice As String                                  'declare that a text string will be used as the filter choice

Set Pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3")         'tell this code where the pivottable is and what its called
Set Fd = Pt.PivotFields("Gene Name")                    'tell this code what pivottable field you are changing
FilterChoice = CStr(ActiveCell)                         'tell this code that the pivottable filter is the text in the cell you double-click

    With Pt                                             'these lines refresh the pivottable after you have double clicked
    Fd.ClearAllFilters
    Fd.CurrentPage = FilterChoice
    Pt.RefreshTable
    End With

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Gene_Chart").Activate             'Sets the chart title. Name the chart as 'Gene_Chart' first
ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
ActiveChart.charttitle.Text = CStr(ActiveCell)

ErrorExit:
Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    msgbox "Dont click on an empty cell"

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Gene_Chart").Activate             'Sets the chart title. Name the chart as 'Gene_Chart' first
ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
ActiveChart.charttitle.Text = "All"

Resume ErrorExit

End Sub
```

When you double click a cell in col A in on your table, the pivot value you double click will be transferred to the pivot table filter field and change the graph. The chart title will also change to show the value you double clicked.

Let me know if you want me to mail you the excel example.

Pete.